# How to Change Default ASP.NET Login Control Database

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication

I'am making a dynamic website.
I'm using a Login Control but I can't use my database to store users.
It stores the users data in another database.
How can I use my own database to store these data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the asp.net membership SPs and tables to your existing db. This 4guys [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx) should have all you need to get it done.

In addition to using the runsql.exe tool you can run the sql scripts directly against your db to create the SPs and needed tables. Those scripts can be found WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 assuming v4.